# Scripting a population sum based on union

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, census, union, voronoi-thiessen

I'm having trouble automating a process to sum one field into a new field, summing whenever the value of an FID field from my Union is the same.

I'm looking to sum the population, stored in field "TheissenPopNonSum", based on polygons which share the same value in "FID_shape", into a field called "TheissenPopSum".

Below is an example of all the polygons that share "FID_shape"=543.

Each of the selected has a population associated that I'm trying to sum into the Theissen polygons generated from the point data.

[image: The Polygons whose population I want to sum]

I know this can be programmed but I don't know how to nest it, so it goes through each FID_shape, sums the associated Population, then moves on.

Here is what I was thinking, but fails:

[image: python]

Answer (score 2):

The Field Calculator is the wrong tool for the job for the summary portion.  Either use the [Summary Statistics tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) to create a summary table that has the FID as the case field and join it to the original and calculate the value over or create a standalone Python script that uses cursors and a dictionary to do the sums and write the values.  For the Python script see my Blog called [Turbo Charging Data Manipulation with Python Cursors and Dictionaries](https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2014/11/08/turbo-charging-data-manipulation-with-python-cursors-and-dictionaries) and adapt the code in the section entitled "Using a Python Dictionary Built using a da SearchCursor to Replace a Summary Statistics Output Table"

Comment: This is perfect, I really appreciate you taking the time to answer and huge effort you've put into that tutorial.